# How to do a 301 redirect from non www to www in aws s3 bucket and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I run a static website on an aws S3 bucket and have cloudfront in front of it to serve https.

Currently the website is only available through [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (Which is what I want).

How can I setup a **301 redirect** from non www to the www page?

Examples:

```
http://example.com =(301 Redirect)> https://www.example.com
https://example.com =(301 Redirect)> https://www.example.com
http://example.com/some-dir/info.jpg =(301 Redirect)> https://www.example.com/some-dir/info.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda@Edge to send a redirect for requests going to the apex. This requires creating a lambda function in the us-east-1 region with a code that checks the hostname the request is going to and conditionally return a redirect. Finally, you need to add it to the CloudFront distribution to the viewer request trigger point.

It's a bit more involved, but it can be done.

Here are some examples:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect
- https://grrr.tech/posts/cloudfront-www-redirect/